# Load a web worker from Quasar Framework's assets directory

Tags: web-worker, quasar-framework

In a Quasar app, from within "assets/subdir/myfile.js", I tried to load "assets/subdir/query.js" as a web worker. I first tried a simple relative path:

```
const myWorker = new Worker('./query.js')
```

And then using the ~assets suggestion [in the docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-assets#Asset-Resolving-Rules):

```
const myWorker = new Worker('~assets/subdir/query.js')
```

Both failed (in `quasar dev` mode) with a complaint in the browser logs about not being able to load that file from http://127.0.0.1:8080/

What did work was moving it into Quasar's "statics" directory:

```
const myWorker = new Worker('statics/query.js')
```

This is not ideal for a few reasons (no linting, no auto-reload when I make an edit, source code in an unexpected place, etc.).

Is there a way to keep a web worker source file under assets, instead of static?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution to this recently: use [worker-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-plugin)

Use `yarn add worker-plugin --dev`, then at the top of quasar.conf.js do:

```
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin')
```

And then in the `build:{...}` section add:

```
extendWebpack (cfg) {
   cfg.plugins.push(new WorkerPlugin())
}
```

I also have:

```
chainWebpack (chain) {
   ...
   chain.output.set('globalObject', 'this') 
},
```

but I'm not sure if that is required or not.

The only change you have to make in your source is to add the `, { type: 'module' }`:

```
const worker = new Worker('./foo.js', { type: 'module' });
```